# Где поставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**...предпочитала природную красоту, макияжной...**

Где ставить запятую и надо вообще ее ставить?

Comment: Запятая не нужна. Впрочем, напишите всё предложение целиком.

Comment: Чтобы дать адекватный ответ, нужно предложение полностью ¯¯\\_(ツ)_/¯¯

Answer (score 2):

**предпочесть**, св. и **предпочитать**, нсв
1) ***кого-что кому-чему*** и с инф.
Счесть, признать по сравнению с кем-, чем-л. другим наиболее отвечающим тем или иным требованиям; отдать преимущество.
*Предпоче́сть всем временам года осень.*
[**Словарь многих выражений**](https://all_words.academic.ru/71271/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Ваше предложение не требует запятой:
[Она] **предпочитала** (что?) **природную красоту** (чему?) **макияжной** [красоте].

Можно перестроить предложение (оно станет понятнее):
Она предпочитала  макияжной красоте природную.

*Растов впервые воочию видел девушку, которая предпочитала гараж салону красоты.*
А. Зорич. Стальной лабиринт

Answer (score -2):

Безусловно, нет нужды в запятой в вашем примере.

Comment: К сожалению, ваш ответ не добавляет ничего нового к уже имеющимся ответам.